# How to count and display multiple rows of different column on TKINTER Treeview GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter, mysql-workbench

My program needs to count and display the number of available assets from the inventory on Tkinter Treeview. The way I did to print the equipment type column on the GUI(last image) was using the SELECT from the EQUIPMENT TYPE query which lists the 11 rows from Equipment type table shown on the GUI. Subsequently, I need to print the total, unavailable, and available items for each equipment type. For example, if there's a total of 10 INTEGRATED PANEL, 3 are available, 7 are unavailable. What is the most easiest and efficient way to accomplish this? The code fragment below is used to insert the Equipment types into the GUI.It was easier to list the equipment types because it was just one column of from the table. For the availability, I'm couldn't imagine an easier way to do it. Thanks.

```
command = "SELECT `Equipment Type` FROM `Equipment Types`"
mycursor.execute(command)
results = mycursor.fetchall()

for i in range(len(results)):
  results[i] = list(results[i])

  tree.insert("", "end", str(results[i][0]), text = str(results[i][0]), tag = [[i][0]], open = TRUE)
```

[image: Equipment type]

[image: Inventory]

[image: GUI output]

[image: Treeview fragment]

[image: edited treeview]

[image: new GUI output]

[image: refresh]

```
def refresh_clicked(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.__init__()
        
        button_refresh = tk.Button(topframe, text = "Refresh", state = NORMAL, command = self.timed_refresh)
        button_refresh.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W, padx = 5, pady = 2)
```

Comment: Your question requires more focus and detail. The question has less to do with treeviews and more to do with getting the data from the database. Much of what you are trying to do could likely be done with an SQL Query but since we have no details of the tables and their data we can't help with that. Investigate the `COUNT()` function for SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL to get what you want:

```py
command = """
SELECT
  et.`Equipment Type`,
  COUNT(i.`Equipment Type`) Total,
  SUM(IF(`Status`="Unavailable",1,0)) Unavailable,
  SUM(IF(`Status`="Available",1,0)) Available
FROM `Equipment Types` et
LEFT JOIN Inventory i ON et.`Equipment Type` = i.`Equipment Type`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
"""

mycursor.execute(command)

for row in mycursor:
    tree.insert("", "end", values=row)
```

Comment: `for row in mycursor:` ? Shouldnt it be `for row in mycursor.fetchall():` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud `mycursor` can be iterated in this way.

Comment: @acw1668 I have edited my post to include the treeview fragment as the last Image. Could you identify what's missing?

Comment: Column #0 always refers to the tree column.  So you should not use it as the index to `Equipment Type` column.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks. I made some changes to it and added the output Image in the description above. Not sure if this is what you meant, but the output looks good.

Comment: If you don't need the column #0, you can add `show="headings"` in `Treeview(...)` and remove the two lines `tree.heading("#0", ...)` and `tree.column("#0", ...)`.

Comment: Better raise another question on the issue.

Comment: @acw1668 Okay. I have asked this as a new question. If you happen to know the solution, do share it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of details about your SQL tables, below is a "best guess" at a solution to get the number of available, unavailable assets of each type from the table.

```
SELECT 
 Inventory.'Equipment Type',
 COUNT(Inventory.'Equipment Type') AS 'Total',
 COUNT(case Inventory.Available when 'Available' then 1 else null end) AS 'Available',
 COUNT(case Inventory.Available when 'Unavailable' then 1 else null end) AS 'Unavailable' 
FROM 
 Inventory
GROUP BY 
 Inventory.'Equipment Type';
```

With my small fake data set this returns

```
Equipment Type |  Total | Available | Unavailable
     A         |    2   |     1     |   1
     B         |    2   |     2     |   0
```